# In Angular, how to define a common set of functions/enums used by several components ?

Tags: angular, enums, undefined

I'm doing an Angular library which includes several components. Most of them need same enums and functions. To factorize this, I put all common functions/enums in a common module.

**files organization**

```
|- src/
  |- common/
     |- common.ts
  |- components/
     |- component1.component.ts
     |- component2.component.ts
     ...
```

**common.ts**

```
module CommonTools {
    export enum FooEnum{
        VALUE1 = <any>"Val 1",
        VALUE2= <any>"Val 2"
    }

    export function  dummy(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

**component1.component.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../common/common.ts"/>
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
...
export class Component1 {
   @Input() attribute1: CommonTools.FooEnum;
   private attribute2: boolean;
   ...       
   constructor() {
       attribute1 = CommonTools.FooEnum.VALUE1;
       attribute2 = false;
   }

   ngOnInit(){
     attribute2 = CommonTools.dummy(); 
   }
}
```

That compiles perfectly ! BUT when I install this library in an Angular project, I get this error :

> "EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/tests/35.html:4:0 caused by: CommonTools is not defined"

Have you got an idea to fix this ?

Comment: you havent exported CommonTools module...and why not just make it a provider?

Comment: You don't need to make a service. Just export them without the wrapper.

Comment: maybe you want a shared module? see the official doc https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module.  import the shared module to the main module

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I know there are several possibilities but I don't know which one is the best. I would like just gather (so wrapped in something) all common enums/functions etc... to use them inside my several components and avoid to copy them in all xxx.component.ts. Provider ? Shared Service ? or other way, I don't know what is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I found is avoid to wrap enums and functions and import one by one in each component like this :

**common.ts**

```
export enum FooEnum{
    VALUE1 = <any>"Val 1",
    VALUE2= <any>"Val 2"
}

export function  dummy(){
    return true;
}
```

**component1.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {FooEnum} from '../common/common'
import {dummy} from '../common/common'
...
export class Component1 {
   @Input() attribute1: FooEnum;
   private attribute2: boolean;
   ...       
   constructor() {
       attribute1 = FooEnum.VALUE1;
       attribute2 = false;
   }

   ngOnInit(){
     attribute2 = dummy(); 
   }
}
```

It's more efficient than import all enums and functions (even unuseful them) in a Module/Provider,  but less pratical for the developer because we have to import them one by one.